# Assets precompile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Precompiling assests with `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` gave error such as:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `empty?' for #<File:0xc1339e8>
```

Stack trace :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionView::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ThemesForRails::AssetsController instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionView::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ThemesForRails::AssetsController instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionView::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ThemesForRails::AssetsController instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionMailer::Base instead. (called from require at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68)
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
Using: Directory Search of /home/roo/Documents/RubyApplications/REALVOLVE/Realvolve-28-Feb/public/assets
Uploading: assets/application-08d5bf8b6880620e6c8aad0f7ffbe7c2.css.gz
rake aborted!
undefined method `empty?' for #<File:0xc1339e8>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/excon-0.10.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:211:in `request_kernel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/excon-0.10.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:92:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:20:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/aws.rb:323:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/requests/aws/put_object.rb:43:in `put_object'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/models/aws/file.rb:119:in `save'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:50:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb:117:in `upload_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb:129:in `block in upload_files'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb:127:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb:127:in `upload_files'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb:135:in `sync'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:29:in `sync'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/asset_sync-0.2.10/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@realvolve/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Is it possible to get some context here? What is causing the deprecation warning? Can you post the code/code file that is giving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.

I tried "bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile" but still same issue.

Also asset_sync is not a problem.

I figured out that axcon gem version "0.10.0" was causing the problem. So I restricted the version to "0.9.5". It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a try ...

For newer Rails versions, you don't have to include the environment any more. Try to use

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile
```

- Ensures that the correct version of rake is used.
- Ensures that the assets were cleaned before compiling them again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) not Heroku or the `rake assets:precompile` task.

We develop **asset_sync** so maybe I can help. I would suggest you try the following:

- Ensure your configuration for **asset_sync** is correct
- Update **asset_sync** to the latest copy. **Version 0.3.0**
- Empty your S3 assets bucket

If none of that works, please post an **issue on Github** and we will look into the problem further for you. We've not had any reports like this, so we may need to look at an anonymised version of your app to try and replicate the issue.

You could also ask **Heroku support** for help on issues like this.